# Error during importing a mysql database

Tags: mysql, database, import, mysql-workbench

I want to import .mwb file to start creating my server. Below is the error code:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '<?xml version="1.0"?> <data grt_format="2.0" document_type="MySQL Workbench Mode' at line 1
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<data grt_format="2.0" document_type="MySQL Workbench Model" version="1.4.4">
<value type="object" struct-name="workbench.Document" id="{9C96C2FB-0BB1-4A76-BE8F-79E5817A1EA6}" struct-checksum="0x7131bf99">
<value type="object" struct-name="workbench.logical.Model" id="{3CB64CD4-2162-4F9E-B626-AD410F02462D}" struct-checksum="0xf4220370" key="logicalModel">
<value _ptr_="0000000023AA1330" type="list" content-type="object" content-struct-name="workbench.logical.Diagram" key="diagrams"/>
<value _ptr_="0000000023AA2600" type="dict" key="customData"/>
<value _ptr_="0000000023AA1B10" type="list" content-type="object" content-    struct-name="model.Marker" key="markers"/>
<value _ptr_="0000000023AA1F70" type="dict" key="options"/>
<value type="string" key="name"></value>
```

What shall I do now?

Comment: How did you create this file and how are you importing it? Please describe this to us, so that we can help you out.

Comment: Like Marc Compte wrote, I had tried to upload MWB file from MySQL Workbench. In a moment I will try to use those guide to convert it to SQL format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`You have an error in your SQL syntax` because you are trying to import the MWB as an SQL. The system looks for SQL sentences and finds an XML and this produces the error you are given.

You should open it as a model and then use forward engineering.

Maybe this video helps you https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fQH9Z9NVEY0

Comment: Great, I did it in this way and I have SQL file. But I've got new errors: "Error
SQL question:

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Schema mydb
-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Schema mydb
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS  `mydb` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8;


MySQL returned information: documentation

#1044 - Access denied for user 'bizon'@'%' to database 'mydb' "

Comment: @Martini The user doesn't have permissions to `CREATE SCHEMA`. If you are using Workbench I am assuming you are using that same user and you have the proper password. If so, then maybe the `mydb` database already exists in the server and you don't have access to it. Try editing the SQL file as a simple text file and replace all references to `mydb` to another more imaginative name to make sure it does not exist. Then execute this in Workbench. If you are working on a hosting provider then maybe you have to create the database from their control panel and remove the CREATE SCHEMA line.

Comment: Exactly - it was a main problem. I changed a name of my database to the same like a admin have and everything is ok now. Thank you.